# Symbole in Wix (candle.exe) error LGHT0311, windows-1252

Tags: wix, heat, windows-1252

I am trying to harvest some folders with heat,candle and light.
One of the drivers that I am harvesting have 32bits dll that have a "®" symbole inside it's description (and it's product name).

one of them : 
name: mfx_mft_h264vd_32.dll , 
description : H.264 Decoder MFT for Intel® HD Graphics

During the heat.exe harvest it is able to handle it :

```
<Component Id="cmp9558AE64A7F57EA5334374D64EF8923F" Guid="9D4432DB-793C-4D1B-A264-C19DE7BDA0CA">
                    <File Id="filB8B8F8A50451F85AED239C3A3C4F0B92" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDirectory)\win32\mfx_mft_h264vd_32.dll">
                        <Class Id="{1A1703E9-3E7C-41C3-AD5A-795CBFB19552}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="H.264 Decoder MFT for Intel® HD Graphics" ThreadingModel="both" />
                    </File>
                    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="MediaFoundation\Transforms\1a1703e9-3e7c-41c3-ad5a-795cbfb19552" Value="H.264 Decoder MFT for Intel® HD Graphics" Type="string" Action="write" />
                    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="MediaFoundation\Transforms\1a1703e9-3e7c-41c3-ad5a-795cbfb19552" Name="InputTypes" Value="7669647300001000800000AA00389B714832363400001000800000AA00389B717669647300001000800000AA00389B714832363400001000900000AA00389B717669647300001000800000AA00389B714156433100001000800000AA00389B71" Type="binary" Action="write" />
                    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="MediaFoundation\Transforms\1a1703e9-3e7c-41c3-ad5a-795cbfb19552" Name="OutputTypes" Value="7669647300001000800000AA00389B714E5631326139AE42BA67FF47CCC13EED7669647300001000800000AA00389B714E56313200001000800000AA00389B71" Type="binary" Action="write" />
                    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="MediaFoundation\Transforms\1a1703e9-3e7c-41c3-ad5a-795cbfb19552" Name="Attributes" Value="41464D490100000015CBA788077B344A9128E64C6703C4D313000000000000000700000000000000" Type="binary" Action="write" />
                    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="MediaFoundation\Transforms\1a1703e9-3e7c-41c3-ad5a-795cbfb19552" Name="MFTFlags" Value="36" Type="integer" Action="write" />
                    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="MediaFoundation\Transforms\Categories\d6c02d4b-6833-45b4-971a-05a4b04bab91\1a1703e9-3e7c-41c3-ad5a-795cbfb19552" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
                </Component>
```

The problem is when I try to use candle.exe, it return the error message:

```
C:\MultipackageInstaller\Developments\MultipackageInstaller\ComponentMsiOSConfig\WixTemplate\HarvestedFiles.wxs(846) : error LGHT0311 : A string was provided with characters that are not available in the specified 
database code page '1252'. Either change these characters to ones that exist in the database's code page, or update the database's code page by modifying one of the following attributes: Product/@Codepage, Module/@
Codepage, Patch/@Codepage, PatchCreation/@Codepage, or WixLocalization/@Codepage.
C:\MultipackageInstaller\Developments\MultipackageInstaller\ComponentMsiOSConfig\WixTemplate\HarvestedFiles.wxs(848) : error LGHT0311 : A string was provided with characters that are not available in the specified 
database code page '1252'. Either change these characters to ones that exist in the database's code page, or update the database's code page by modifying one of the following attributes: Product/@Codepage, Module/@
Codepage, Patch/@Codepage, PatchCreation/@Codepage, or WixLocalization/@Codepage.
```

So I looked to the code page 1252 and it seem that the "®" is handle by this encoding format. 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

I tried to force the code format to wix, but no changes.

Do you have an idea why do I haves thoses messages? 
Is it indeed the "®" symbole the problem? 
And why it is not supported by wix either if it is in the codepage 1252? 
and finaly, what solutions do I have?

Thank you to have read me until there, and I hope that someone have an idea on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a problem with the visual studio cache.

I can't really explain it, but after clean my "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio" folder, and rebuildt everything, I didn't have the problem anymore.